# why is my QNetwork build not outputting the right shape?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, dqn

So I'm trying to use a DQN agent, but when I try to build the QNetwork it emits an output tensor of shape (50,50,7500) instead of (7500,). I need it to be the latter.
My input spec (observation_spec) is of shape (50,50,7500).  I tried ChatGPT and I gave up with it after hours.  I could not find a solution searching StackOverflow, so I'm posting this here.

Below is my code:

```
def dense_layer(self, num_units):
    return tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        num_units,
        activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,
        kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling(
            scale=2.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='truncated_normal'))

def _build_q_network(self):

    dense_layers = [self.dense_layer(num_units) for num_units in [64,64]]

    q_values_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
        7500,
        activation=None,
        kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform(
            minval=-0.03, maxval=0.03),
        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(-0.2))
    q_net = sequential.Sequential(dense_layers + [q_values_layer])
    return q_net

self.q_net = self._build_q_network()
print(self.q_net.compute_output_signature(self.observation_spec))  # returns TensorSpec(shape=(50, 50, 7500), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)
```